# How to know which check box has just been toggled within a mass created checkbox from tkinter or related libraries

Tags: python, tkinter, logic, customtkinter

let's say I've this piece of code where it give me a hundred check boxes created by a for loop(I'm working with a switch in customtkinter but it has the same logic as checkbox in tkinter), those check box could either be off or on initially however, I just need to know **what is the latest check box that has been toggled**, its position or at least what it called so that I could work on it. I've done some research but I couldn't figured out how to work on this, here is the part of that code for the check box, I've not assigned the variable to it since I'm trying to figure out the logic first but any help would be much appreciated, thank you!

```
        with open(r"D:\Largecodefile\TkinterApply\List1.txt",'r') as f:
        Lines=f.read().splitlines()
    
    for i,val in enumerate(Lines):
        switch = ct.CTkSwitch(master=self.scrollable_framel, text=val,command=self.changestate)
        switch.grid(row=i, column=0, padx=10, pady=(0, 20))
        self.scrollable_frame_switches.append(switch)
```

The command=self.changestate doesn't seem to return anything as of right now and it's just mainly used to run the function and that's it so I don't think it'd be of great help either :(

Edit: I'm thinking of cross comparing between 2 list of off or on state after a certain event occured for those 100 boxes but that doesn't seem to be a good idea, and perhaps it's the same thing for creating 100 function for this purpose as well since it'd take a lot of time to process as the list get longer

Comment: The function/method passed to `command` is something you have to define. If you haven't defined a method named `changestate` within the same class as your `for` loop, the checkboxes won't do anything.

Comment: @JRiggles thank you for your suggestion, I could manage to put some variable into that function rightnow, but is there a way so that we could actually know what specific boxes just got toggle and use that information to give it to the function?

Comment: It wasn't a suggestion so much as an explananatiton. That's how the `command` parameter works - *you* have to define the function in order for it to do anything. But yes, theoretically you could pass the value of `i` to the function to figure out the `index` of the button that was pressed - see below :)

Comment: @JRiggles I've done something similar to that if I understand you correctly,I set it as lambda: changestate(i)  and try to check what the i value return after everyclick. However the value that got return are always the list length since it's the last value that has been assigned as a checkbox. Is it that I'm missing something? Thank you

Comment: You've almost got it! See my answer below - hopefully that helps!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're on the right track, but you have to set the value of `i` to a variable the `lambda` can pass: `command=lambda button_index=i: changestate(button_index)` - that way the value is updated for each button!

Here's an example of how to pass the index value `i` to the event handler function `changestate` (I've removed `self` here since this isn't in a `class` that I can see, but if you're using a class, just add `self.`)

```
def changestate(button_index):
    print(button_index)  # do whatever you want here!


for i, val in enumerate(Lines):
    switch = ct.CTkSwitch(
        master=self.scrollable_framel,
        text=val,
        # pass the latest index value to the lambda for each button
        command=lambda button_index=i: changestate(button_index)
    )
        switch.grid(row=i, column=0, padx=10, pady=(0, 20))
        self.scrollable_frame_switches.append(switch)
```

Comment: Woahhh, this is perfect and is exactly what I need. Thank you so much, will update my code right now!!!

Comment: Glad I could help out - lambdas can be tricky, but they're a huge asset once you figure them out!